# Is it possible to pass in a git repo tag to an ADO build pipeline as a variable?

Tags: git, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Is it possible to pass in a git tag associated with a build in an Azure DevOps build pipeline?

Our tags contain the version of the software being built and released and I want to pass the version in to the build process so it can be included in the code that is being built.

I know there are pre-defined variables for things like `Build.BuildNumber`, and `Build.SourceBranch`, but I want to be able to define get the git tag associated with the underlying git repo that the build is based on.

Comment: I'm fairly certain `Build.SourceBranch` would contain the tag if the build is started from tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build version is a tag (and not branch/commit) you can get the tag value in these 2 variables:

```
Build.SourceBranch = refs/tags/test
Build.SourceBranchName = test
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You can define a CI trigger based on your tag.

Please refer to the following page of azure devops documentation:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

As you can see, you have different options define your trigger to consume tags. Refer to the YAML definitions below:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      refs/tags/{tagname}
    exclude:
      refs/tags/{othertagname}
```

Or

```
# specific branch build
trigger:
  tags:
    include:
    - v2.*
    exclude:
    - v2.0
```